# C# Winforms Custom Form Looks Different On Different Machines

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

The program I'm working on renders perfectly fine on one machine and totally wrong on the other one.

here's the photos;

[image]
[image]

As you can see at the second picture, all of the controls are shifted to the left.
And the right part of the form is empty. Also half of the little arrows on the left got lost.

Both machines have high end Nvidia graphics card have same DPI.

Comment: Do you use custom controls ? It is difficult to help without any piece of code ...

Comment: Yes. I changed the FormBorderStyle to none and than add various picture Boxes to give it a custom layout. I would post some code, but its kinda big, so I don't even know what to post. What I don't understand is why does it work perfectly on one machine and not on the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of likely causes for this:

1. You are using two different OSes. 8 and XP render the same controls completely different.
2. You are using different visual styles (Aero on one, Classic on the other).
3. You did not anchor your controls. Anchoring allows controls on the form to dynamically layout depending on the size of the window.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Both machines have windows 7 installed on them and both of them have same visual styles(Aero). I just checked the anchoring and all of the controls inside my form seems to be anchored correctly. And just out of curiosity what do you do if you use the program on different OSes and get different results?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply; I did not see your comment until today. The problem you are having is mostly due to WinForms. I have migrated most of my projects to WPF, since it removes a ton of layout problems which WinForms had. No matter what framework you are using, however, it may just be necessary to hard-code values for different OSes. I know this is an ugly hack, but in some situations it is the only alternative.